# getDocument() constantly returns a null value

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an XML file using Java that lives on a network drive...I have reviewed lots of XML parsing info here but cannot find the answer I need... the problem is that the getDocument() routine constantly returns a null value even though the parser gets a accurate location and file name.

Here is the code...

```
String ThisXMLFile = XMLFileData.getPath();
DOMParser myXMLParser = new DOMParser(); 
myXMLParser.parse(ThisXMLFile);   
Document doc = myXMLParser.getDocument();
```

Some notes:

I had to use getPath() as the getName() function did not return the fully qualified file name and path - the XML file lives on a network directory and that directory is mapped on my PC to the 'V' drive

I have imported all the required class header files for DOM objects

The variable names given above are real and accurate so if I have inadvertently used a reserved keyword in a variable declaration then please offer correction.

I have extensive programming experience in a few languages but this is my first real Java app.

all the lines of code and the variables above work, until I reach the last line and then getDocument() just sets the doc variable to null... which makes the rest of the program break.

Comment: What library are you using to parse the XML ??

Comment: import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser;

Comment: Any classes whose package starts with `com.sun.` are considered internal implementation details, which applications should never reference directly.  Instead, use `DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()` to create a [DocumentBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) instance, then pass `new File(ThisXMLFile)` to the DocumentBuilder’s parse method.

Comment: tried this too, thanks for the response, but I still get nothing but a null value returned by the parser...and the file is in the right spot, the directories have no white paces in them... very confusing ...this should be actually a simple function...

Comment: I noticed something way strange with using the DocumentBuilderFactory...when I type in the following code: DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()  - 'newInstance()' is appearing with italics applied to the font, no other function call does this... I have noticed that when I see something like this it usually represents a problem with the code.. these are the libraries  Iam importing to use this feature import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
            XMLInputFactory XMLFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            XMLStreamReader XMLReader = XMLFactory.createXMLStreamReader(myXMLStream);
            while(XMLReader.hasNext())
            {
                if (XMLReader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT)
                {        
                   String XMLTag = XMLReader.getLocalName();
                   if(XMLTag.equals("value"))
                   {
                      String idValue = XMLReader.getAttributeValue(null, "id");
                      if (idValue.equals(ElementName))
                      {
                        System.out.println(idValue);
                        XMLReader.nextTag();
                        System.out.println(XMLReader.getElementText());
                      }
                   }
               }    
               XMLReader.next();
            }
```

so this is the code I finally got to...it works and solves the issue of retrieving specific XML data fro a XML file. I wanted at first to use nodelists, elements, Documents, etc but those functions never did work for me... this one did - thanks to all for the answers given as they helped me think this one through...

Answer (score 0):

I Believe that your are calling the wrong method... according to your code, you're executing: `DOMParser.parse(systemId)` when you need to call: `DOMParser.parse(InputSource)` ...

to create an InputSource you can can do this:

```
InputSource source = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(ThisXMLFile));
myXMLParser.parse(source);
Document doc = myXMLParser.getDocument();
```

NOTE: remember to close the opened FileInputStream!!!

Comment: thanks for this, I can't get it to work though, getDocument() still returns null...

Comment: Can you read the content of the file using FileInputStream ??

Comment: yes I can...odd though instead of 'v:\xmlfiledir\xmlfile.xml' I am getting 'V:\\xmlfiledir\\xmlfile.xml' - not sure if the double slash means anything I am assuming this is done for cross platform compatibility...

Comment: Have you tried to read the same file on a real disk, not a network directory ??

Comment: just moved a copy of the target directory to my C drive and tried it again, no luck, still returns a null value... very frustrating...